# By Scrolling webpage, form wrapper moving left side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a issue in CSS. When I am scrolling down the webpage all form elements in application are moving slightly left side. How to avoid that one please help me. Form class name is form-horizontal.

Comment: add the code...

Comment: please provide more information about the code.